# How to insert setState value into useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I watched a Youtube video and I made my own recipe app. I'm a beginner at React.js and I've been solving this problem for about 2 days. Seems that i cant pass the value of my state to useEffect hook. Here's an example of my code. The error says

"React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'query'. Either include it or remove the dependency array" and everytime I typed in the input box it triggers the useEffect hook. Thank you and your help is very much appreciated.

```
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const [query, setQuery] = useState('steak');

const updateSearch = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    console.log(search)
}

const getSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
}

useEffect(() => {   // error Is from the Query variable
    const GetRecipe = async () => {
        const APP_ID = "3834705e";
        const APP_KEY = "c23e9514f82c2440abf54b21edd4c3dc";
        const res = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        setRecipes(data.hits);
      }
    GetRecipe();
},[getSearch]) //this triggers everytime I typed in the input box which is not it is supposed to

return(
    <div className='recipelist'>

        <form onSubmit={getSearch}>
            <input type="search" onChange={updateSearch}/>
            <button type='submit'>submit</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error tells you, when using a `useEffect` hook, that hook can receive two arguments, the first one is the handler effect and the second one is an array containing all dependencies that effect will use, so as you are using the query state into the http url, you need to pass that dependency into the array, so could be something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {   // error Is from the Query variable
    const GetRecipe = async () => {
        const APP_ID = "3834705e";
        const APP_KEY = "c23e9514f82c2440abf54b21edd4c3dc";
        const res = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        setRecipes(data.hits);
      }
    GetRecipe();
},[getSearch, query])
```

so what is actually doing the array dependency, as React docs says, array dependency it's used to check if the effect should execute again based on its dependencies, so in your code everything you type something, `getSearch` method is re-creating again and again in memory, so it will check the last `getSearch` function that it took and compare it with the new ones, so it will check as equally checker like fn1 === fn2, so due to both function are exactly the same, both keeps different space in memory, so both are different objects, check this [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) to understand the concept.

Here you have the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) too